# pandas filter dates to last most recent 3 months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I want to filter a pandas data frame to the last most recent 3 months.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.DataFrame(['2016-11-01', '2016-12-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01'], columns=['date'])
dates.date = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates.date)
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=90)
print (lastMonth.strftime("%Y-%m"))
dates[dates.date >= lastMonth]
```

This snippet sort of already works, but has the length of a month hard coded to 30 days. How can I use a `pd.Timedelta('-3 month')` (which does not seem to work like this) to achieve a more robust function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`offsets`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), because `Timedelta` only does not work with months:

```
lastMonth = first - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
#lastMonth = first - pd.offsets.relativedelta(months=3)
```

---

```
lastMonth = first - pd.Timedelta(months=3)
```

> ValueError: cannot construct a Timedelta from the passed arguments, allowed keywords are 
>       [weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds]